# Is there someone who try to port Kigg asp.net mvc example to MVC beta

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kigg

I've downloaded Kigg example from codeplex, but it's seems to be outdated.

Is there a version for ASP.NET MVC Beta? Is there someone who try to port it(I've tried but without success because of lack of knowledge)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I upgraded Kigg from Preview 2 to Beta in two steps. I went from Preview 2 to Preview 3 in June and then went from Preview 3 to Beta a couple of weeks ago. Basically I just followed the steps in the "Upgrading an Existing Preview 2 Application to Preview 3" section of the Preview 3 ReadMe Release notes and then did the same with the "Upgrading an Existing Preview 3 Application to Beta" section of the Beta release notes. Below are a couple of links where I described doing so but really there's not much more there than what I stated above.

- http://danhounshell.com/blogs/dan/archive/2008/06/21/upgrading-kigg-to-asp-net-mvc-preview-3.aspx
- http://danhounshell.com/blogs/dan/archive/2008/11/24/looking-at-asp-net-mvc-following-my-own-lead.aspx